# Attach image and send using email without SD card in android

Tags: java, android, email-attachments

Hi so I'am developing an app where there is a feature that print screens and able to attach in email especially gmail. So I did some research and all I read was about using external storage such as memory card. What I want though is to do the feature without using SD card like attaching it in bitmap, base64 or any possible way? Is it really impossible to do?

Comment: "all I read was about using external storage such as memory card" -- [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on most Android devices. "What I want though is to do the feature without using SD card" -- have the file on internal storage (e.g., `getCacheDir()`), then use `FileProvider` to create the `Uri` to use with `EXTRA_STREAM` on your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

Comment: Can you pls provide some examples in using getCacheDir , FileProvider and URI? I haven't done something like this before.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html